# TextViews not update in android UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, bluetooth, textview

we have two activities one is where we make the connection via bluetooth and managing the blutooth other one is the update the UI where we want to update the GUI containing the TextViews.
We successfully send and recieve the message within two activities and vice versa.

```
private OnMessageReceivedListener dataReceivedListener = new OnMessageReceivedListener() {
    public void OnMessageReceived(String device, String message) {
        //t.setText(message);
        Log.d("Message" , message);
        msg = message;
        UpdateGUI();

    }
};
```

THE above function recieves the message and we did that successfully.

```
 private void UpdateGUI() {
    //i++;
    //tv.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    myHandler.post(myRunnable);
 }

 final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {  
    btBoard.UpdateYoursBoard(mystring);

    }
 };
```

The above function of connection class calls the method of our GUI class and send a recieved message to it.

In our GUI class we want this

```
    public void UpdateYoursBoard(String positions)
{
    Log.d("Positions" , positions);
    tv.setText(positions);
```

};
we successfully recieved the message in log.d but when we want to change our textview text it gives following errors.

```
       java.lang.NullPointerException
       at net.clc.bt.Board.UpdateYoursBoard(Board.java:3460)
```

**NOTE** : we are working with bluetooth and we have 3 mobile connected simultaneously and UpdateYourBoard will change the TextViews of 3 mobiles GUI's.

kindly help me to fix the problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your Board class is far too big. 3 500 lines in a java file is very bad idea. Design more, decouple and split things. You are missing the divide and conqueer principle of IT.

In your case, tv is null. How and when do you get a reference to it ? If you used findViewById in your onCreate method (after super.onCreate has been called), it should work.

Comment: thnx for reply. we are initializing it after super.oncreate. the problem is from our connecion class we are calling method of our board class and want to update its textview text. our board class activity is in front. dont know why it is giving us NullPointer exception.

Comment: thnx it is solved by declaring it as Public static textView tv and set text as this.tv,setText(mystring);

Comment: Thx for accepting the answer, and I am glad that helped. But I don't understand why tv should be static. Generally speaking, using static UI fields in Android is not a good idea. A view is linked to an instance of a class that is displayed for some time. This instance will die and its views won't be displayed. Keeping a reference on them just prevents the garbage collector to get rid of entities that are useless. Instances don't share views, each instance of an activity has its own views and they have a meaning only during the life time of this activity.

Answer (score 0):

The reference to your TextView 'tv' is null. Initialize it somewhere using `findViewById()` or some other appropriate method.

Check your scopes etc so that the reference is maintained properly at the point where you call the `setText()` method.

Comment: it is working fine when i called it from my GUI class. the function set text successfully but when i call this method from my other activity class it is giving me NULLPointer exception

Comment: thnx it is solved by declaring it as Public static textView tv and set text as this.tv,setText(mystring);